# Adding file name in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a single csv file chr1.step1.csv, say it has five columns. I can read this as follows:

```
df=pd.read_csv('chr1.step1.csv',sep='\t',header=None)
df.head()
0 1 2 3 4 5
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
```

How can I add 6th column as file name `chr1.step1.csv`, such as:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 chr1.step1.csv
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 chr1.step1.csv
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 chr1.step1.csv
```

Its only one file, not multiple files.

Comment: `df[6] = "chr1.step1.csv"`?

Comment: Thanks. But I need to take the argument from file name.

Comment: like `filename='chr1.step1.csv'; df=pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\t',header=None); df[6]=filename`? i think that's basically all you can do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that 6th column name is `Name File`, and considering the file is in the path `csv = '/home/User/Documents/file.csv'` or `csv = 'file.csv'`, one can do that using the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module.

```
import os.path

df['Name File'] = os.path.basename(csv)
```

One might also do, as [@tdy suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453210/adding-file-name-in-a-column-in-pandas/67455922#comment119225635_67453210). Assign the name of the file to a variable

```
filename='chr1.step1.csv';
```

Then, assuming the df already exists (else one needs to read it, with something like `df=pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\t',header=None)`), assign the file name to the cells in a new column

```
df['Name File'] = filename
```

---

**Extra**: If one has a directory with lots of csv files

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os.path

# Create a list of all CSV files
files = glob.glob("*.csv")

# Create an empty list to append the df
filenames = []

for csv in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    df['Name File'] = os.path.basename(csv)
    filenames.append(df)
```